# How to specify run id in a DAG run in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

When triggering a DAG from the webserver and go to the graph view the run id is something like below:

[image]

I can specify this name when running through the command line using 'airflow trigger_dag' and specifying the 'run_id' but I don't know how to specify this ID when triggering the DAG through the webserver?

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Triggering a dag from the UI is clicking on a button. what exactly is your question?

Comment: When you click the button to trigger the DAG a run ID is generated as above starting with 'manual'. But I want to be able to specify this ID as you can when triggering the DAG through the command line. so instead of 'manual .. .. ..' it would be the name that i have specified

Comment: Hey @tribo32 did u find something ?

Comment: @SHIVANSHNARAYAN Unfortunately not, I believe that in the current version there is no way to name DAG runs through the GUI. One alternative based on your needs could be to create a rudimentary front end which runs commands via the command line where you can give the option to specify the DAG run name. Not an ideal solution but it is the way I am leaning as I will have multiple users and want them to be able to locate their DAG runs easily

Answer (score 2):

Airflow 2.0 released stable REST APIs where we can mention specific dag_run_id. Here is the link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run

`dag_run_id`: The value of this field can be set only when creating the object. If you try to modify the field of an existing object, the request fails with an BAD_REQUEST error.

If not provided, a value will be generated based on execution_date.

If the specified dag_run_id is in use, the creation request fails with an ALREADY_EXISTS error.

This together with DAG_ID are a unique key.

`execution_date`:
The execution date. This is the time when the DAG run should be started according to the DAG definition. The value of this field can be set only when creating the object. If you try to modify the field of an existing object, the request fails with an BAD_REQUEST error. This together with DAG_ID are a unique key.

`state`: It is recommended not to provide this parameter while triggering REST APIs.

`conf`: JSON object describing additional configuration parameters.
The value of this field can be set only when creating the object. If you try to modify the field of an existing object, the request fails with an BAD_REQUEST error.